# mongoDB "multiple" select

Tags: mongodb

I am not exactly sure on how this can be called, but what I want to do is select two different values with a limit; for example select 5 documents with of type "A", and 5 of type "B"; something like:

```
db.students.find({class: 'A'}).limit(10);
db.students.find({class: 'B'}).limit(10);
```

can this be done with only ONE query?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [**$in**](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/OR+operations+in+query+expressions) to achieve this

`db.students.find({class: {$in: ['A', 'B'] }}).limit(10)`

Answer (score 1):

This is not the same output.

```
db.students.find({class: {$in: ['A', 'B'] }}).limit(10)
```

This will limit the Results of Class A and B to 10.

Hence, for example **class A matches 10 Students** and **class B matches 10 Students**. The result would be 10 Students.

While this one:

```
db.students.find({class: 'A'}).limit(10);
db.students.find({class: 'B'}).limit(10);
```

Will give 20 Students